# Producer Consumer Pattern with return value

Tags: c#

I want to implement a producer consumer pattern, with return value. Instead of using `Task.Result` , I use a more primitive way.. which is having a `Result` property, and make use of `ManualResetEvent.Wait()` and `ManualResetEvent.Set()` to make sure the `Result` is set.

What is the pros and cons of my implementation? Thanks.

```
internal class Job
{
    public int Result;
    public ManualResetEvent ManualResetEvent { get; set; }
    public Job()
    {
        ManualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    }
    public void doWork()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Result = 123;
        ManualResetEvent.Set();
    }
}


class Program
{
    static  BlockingCollection<Job> Queue = new BlockingCollection<Job>();

    const int TOTAL_JOB_COUNT = 100;

    const int TOTAL_WORKER_THREAD = 2;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        for(int i=0;i<TOTAL_JOB_COUNT;i++)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(() =>
            {
                var returnedValue = EnqueueAndGetResult(new Job());
                Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} {returnedValue}");
            });

            t.Start();
        }

        for(int i=0;i<TOTAL_WORKER_THREAD;i++)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(doWork);
            t.Start();
        }

    }

    static int EnqueueAndGetResult(Job job)
    {
        int result;
        Queue.Add(job);
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} A job is enqueued.");
        job.ManualResetEvent.WaitOne();
        result = job.Result;
        return result;
    }



    static void doWork()
    {
        Job _job;
        while(Queue.TryTake(out _job))
        {
            _job.doWork();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you need a thread?  Are you trying to run job in parallel?  You know when the entire task is completed when the total number of response is the same a the Total_Job_Count.

Comment: Sorry to be uncleared, i was trying to simulate 100 web service call simultaneously , with two worker thread as consumer.

Comment: It doesn't matter the task.  The code flow should be the same.  There isn't a way to tell when each job is completed nor when all the jobs are completed with the way you have to code organized.  That is why I posted my code using backgroundworker.

Answer (score 0):

I like using a background worker :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static  List<Job> Queue = new List<Job>();

        const int TOTAL_JOB_COUNT = 100;

        const int TOTAL_WORKER_THREAD = 2;

        public static ManualResetEvent manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_JOB_COUNT; i++)
            {
                Job newJob = new Job();
                Object thisLock = new Object();
                lock (thisLock)
                {
                    Queue.Add(newJob);
                }
                newJob.state.id = i;
                newJob.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(newJob_ProgressChanged);
                newJob.DoWork +=new DoWorkEventHandler(newJob.doWork);
                newJob.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            manualResetEvent.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine("All jobs completed");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static void newJob_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Job job = sender as Job;
            State state = job.state;
            Console.WriteLine("Job Completed,  ID: '{0}', Results = '{1}'", state.id, state.Result);
            Object thisLock = new Object();
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Queue.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (state.id == Queue[i].state.id)
                    {
                        Queue.RemoveAt(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (Queue.Count == 0) manualResetEvent.Set();
            }

        }

    }
    public class Job : BackgroundWorker
    {
        public State state = new State();
        public Job()
        {
            this.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        }
        public void doWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            state.Result = 123;
            this.ReportProgress(100, state);
            this.Dispose();
        }
    }
    public class State
    {
        public int id;
        public int Result { get; set; }
    }
}
```